# Why isn't this randomising the order?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I'm using Zend framework and trying to get the results to be in a random order. This returns the results but doesn't seem to vary the order. Any ideas?

```
    class Model_DBTable_Tblquotes extends Zend_Db_Table
{
public function getQuotes()
 { 
  $select = $this->select();  
        $select->setIntegrityCheck(false) 
               ->from('tblQuotes',array('id','quote','author','dateCreated')) 
      ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))
      ->limit(25, 0);

        return $this->fetchAll($select);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 ->order('RAND()')
```

instead of

```
 ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))
```

You can also use

```
 $select->__toString();
```

On your db obj to get a string of the query so you could echo it and look at it to see whats wrong.

Comment: Turned out my original code was working fine. I did however have a caching problem with windows 7 and my version of filezilla - how annoying!! :) Mark you as the answer as your answer was potentially useful

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass in the expression as a string: "RANDOM()"

example: ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RANDOM()'));